# How to show a dialog with Android?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Total noob here. Went through Google's developer reference but didn't find enough detail for me to understand. I am trying to make a dialog box appear when hitting an Action Bar item.

I have 2 classes. The first one is only the DialogFragment, using a AlertDialog builder with a positive button and a negative button.

The 2nd class is the Activity, in which I would like to call my DialogFragment and display the dialog, however I when I try to do that under the OnOptionsItemSelected function, using the following code:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new CreateWordListDialog();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "createWordList");
```

I get a "cannot resolve method" line error on the 2nd line. Where should this line be placed? I must be missing something here.

Comment: There is no such method `Fragment.show()` as `Fragment` is not an `AlertDialog`; you must be imagining `AlertDialog.show()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the function `OnOptionsItemSelected` you can construct your AlertDialog, you don't need to create another class for this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.title) //
        .setMessage(R.string.message) //
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.positive), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }) //
        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.parking_no_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
builder.show();
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better approach

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio android.support.v4 etc are not encluded by default. So either add these dependencies manually or use  `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`  and the issue will be solved